# JPA .in() predicate with tuples as arguments

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entites linked by a one-to-many join:

```java
@Entity
public class UserInfoEntity {
    @Id
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    String userId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userInfo", targetEntity = ColorEntity.class)
    public final Set<ColorEntity> colors = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class ColorEntity {
    @Id
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_info_id")
    UserInfoEntity userInfo;

    @Column(name = "color", nullable = false)
    String color;
}
```

I wanted to write a repository method `find(List< Pair<String, Set<String>> > )` that takes as parameters a list of tuples (userId, {colors...}) and returns all users where userId matches, AND colors contains **any** of the given colors.

The raw SQL would be something like:

```sql
SELECT u.* FROM user_info u
LEFT JOIN color c on u.id = c.user_info_id
WHERE (u.user_id, c.color) IN ( ('Alice', 'Red'), ('Bob', 'Green'), ('Cindy', 'Brown'));
```

So for the data set

```
ID  Person name  Colors
--  -----------  ---------
1   Alice        Red, Blue
2   Bob          Green
```

`find( [ (Alice, Red), (Bob, Green), (Cindy, Brown) ])`  should return records for Alice and Bob.

I'm trying to use JPA's `CriteriaBuilder` and perhaps the `.in()` predicate. I know how `.in` would work if the argument were a direct column/field in the entity, but in this case, I need to construct a tuple, and I'm not sure how to feed that tuple into the predicate.

So the best option I can think of right now is to construct a predicate for each item in the list, and .or() them. Something like this:

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<UserInfoEntity> query = cb.createQuery(UserInfoEntity.class);
Root<UserInfoEntity> root = query.from(UserInfoEntity.class);

List<Predicate> colorsClause = new ArrayList<>();

for (Pair p : pairs) {
  Predicate userClause = cb.equal(root.get("userId"), p.getLwdr());
  CriteriaBuilder.In<String> colorClause = cb.in(root.join("colors").get("color"));
  colorClause.value(p.getRight());
  colorsClause.add(cb.and(userClause, colorClause));
}

query.where(cb.or(colorsClause.toArray(new Predicate[0])))).distinct(true);
TypedQuery<UserInfoEntity> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query);
return typedQuery.getResultList();
```

But in looking at the hibernate SQL dump, there are multiple nested ORs, and isn't like the simple sql above. Is there a more efficient way to write this query that matches the SQL shown above?